# Append/Add JsObject into JsArray in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3, json

I am newbie to Play Framework, I need to `append/add` `JsObject` elements into `JsArray`

**Aim(What I need)**

```
 {"s_no":1,"s_name":"one",
    ,"sub_s":  [{"sub_s_no":1,"sub_s_name":"one_sub","sub_s_desc":"one_sub"},{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"}]},
{"s_no":2,"s_name":"two","sub_s":[{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"},
    {"sub_s_no":3,"sub_s_name":"three_sub","sub_s_desc":"three_sub"}]}
```

**What I Got**

**JsObject 1**

```
{"s_no":1,"s_name":"one",
,"sub_s":[{"sub_s_no":1,"sub_s_name":"one_sub","sub_s_desc":"one_sub"},{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"}]}
```

**JsObject 2**

```
{"s_no":2,"s_name":"two","sub_s":[{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"},
{"sub_s_no":3,"sub_s_name":"three_sub","sub_s_desc":"three_sub"}]}
```

I have got two `JsObject` and will get more than two, I need to `add/append` these all `JsObjects` into `JsArray`

I tried with `.+:`,`.append` methods which gave empty `JsArray` values

Comment: Your "Aim" is not valid json.  Also your JsObject 1 has an extra comma which means it also isn't valid json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why getting an empty `JsArray` is because `JsArray` is immutable so the original `JsArray` will not modified.  You need to *assign* the result of the append to a new variable in order for it to work how you expect.

```
val jsonString1 = """{"s_no":1,"sub_s":[1,2]}"""
val jsonString2 = """{"s_no":2,"sub_s":[3,4]}"""

val jsObj1 = Json.parse(jsonString1)
val jsObj2 = Json.parse(jsonString2)

val emptyArray = Json.arr()
val filledArray = emptyArray :+ obj1 :+ obj2

Json.prettyPrint(emptyArray)
Json.prettyPrint(filledArray)
```

And some of the REPL output

```
> filledArray: play.api.libs.json.JsArray = [{"s_no":1,"s_name":"one","sub_s":[{"sub_s_no":1,"sub_s_name":"one_sub","sub_s_desc":"one_sub"},{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"}]},{"s_no":2,"s_name":"two","sub_s":[{"sub_s_no":2,"sub_s_name":"two_sub","sub_s_desc":"two_sub"},{"sub_s_no":3,"sub_s_name":"three_sub","sub_s_desc":"three_sub"}]}]
> // pretty print of the empty array
> res1: String = [ ]
> // pretty print of the filled array
> res2: String = [ {"s_no" : 1 ...}, {"s_no" : 2 ...} ]
```

Comment: JoseM, I am using `for loop` for getting a `JsObjects` as it may return any numbers based on my values.
I used below code but it stores only the last `JsObjects` in `filledArray`. previous `objects` are not stored.

`val emptyArray = Json.arr()
var filledArray = emptyArray
  for (testdata <- testList) {  
    val testObject:JsObject = Json.obj("s_no" -> testdata) 
  filledArray = emptyArray :+ testObject
          
  }  
  prinln("filledArray:="+filledArray)`

Comment: In for loop I used  `filledArray = filledArray :+ testObject` instead of  `filledArray = emptyArray :+ testObject` it solved my problem.Thanks friend.

Comment: If you have an existing `Seq` of `JsObjects` you can just do `JsArray(jsObjectsSeq)`.  If you want to add it to an existing array you can do `val updatedArray = existingArray ++ JsArray(jsObjectsSeq)`